# Wrapping symmtric key with public RSA key causes DOMException (InvalidAccessError)

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, cryptography

I am trying to wrap a symmetric key using the Web Crypto API but get an error:
`DOMException: key.usages does not permit this operation`

[image: Error in codesanbox with open dev tools1]

Still very new to using the Web Crypto API so I do not fully understand why this is an issue. I want to wrap the symmetric key with the Public Key and later one unwrap it with my Private Key.

I extracted the problem into a small code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-driscoll-v0itr?file=/src/index.ts

Alternatively, the following steps can be used to reproduce the problem.

- Generate CryptoKey Pair (I used RSA here)
- Generate Symmetric Key
- Call

  ```js
  window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
      "raw",
      fileKey,
      publicKey,
      publicKey.algorithm.name
  );
  ```

Here is full code from the sandbox:

```js
sync function foo() {
  try {
    const cryptoKeyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        modulusLength: 4096,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: "SHA-256"
      },
      true,
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );
    const publicKey = cryptoKeyPair.publicKey;

    const fileKey = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      { name: "AES-GCM", length: 256 },
      true,
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    );

    const wrapKeyResult = await window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
      "raw",
      fileKey,
      publicKey,
      publicKey.algorithm.name
    );
    // ^^ here we get error: DOMException: key.usages does not permit this operation
    /** 
    * {
    *  code: 15
    *  message: "key.usages does not permit this operation"
    *  name: "InvalidAccessError"
    * }
    */
    console.log("Wrapped Key", wrapKeyResult);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("something went wrong", error);
    throw error; 
}

foo()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("I succeeded!");
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log("I failed with ", error));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`generateKey()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey) the wrong [key usages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey#parameters) are applied. Correct would be `wrapKey` and `unwrapKey`, since the RSA key pair is used for wrapping/unwrapping the symmetric AES-GCM key:

```js
async function foo() {
    try {
        const cryptoKeyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
            {
                name: "RSA-OAEP",
                modulusLength: 4096,
                publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
                hash: "SHA-256"
            },
            true,
            ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey"]                      // Apply wrapKey and unwrapKey here! 
        );
        const publicKey = cryptoKeyPair.publicKey;

        const fileKey = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
            { name: "AES-GCM", length: 256 },
            true,
            ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
        );

        const wrapKeyResult = await window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
            "raw",
            fileKey,
            publicKey,
            publicKey.algorithm.name
        );
        console.log("Wrapped Key", new Uint8Array(wrapKeyResult));
  
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("something went wrong", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

foo()
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("I succeeded!");
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("I failed with ", error));
```